# Unable to reserve external IPv6 address on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ipv6

I have a Google Cloud account and I am using a Compute Engine VM. Recently GCP started providing IPv6 for their VM instances. And I am in a supported region: *us-east*.

I created a new custom VPC with dual stack. In **IP addresses** under **VPC network**, I see the new IPv6 address assigned and used by my instance as an **External**, but **Ephemeral** address. Please look at the last line of the figure below:

[image: GCP IP addresses screenshot]

I have no problem with the newly assigned IPv6 address on my instance. However, I want to reserve that address and make it **Static**. While trying to use the **RESERVE** button for this, it returns: `Error: Request contains an invalid argument.`

Answer (score 1):

Not possible yet unless your GCP project is granted Alpha access to the feature:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#reserve-regional-ipv6

> Important: Static regional external IPv6 addresses are available as a
> limited Preview feature. Contact your sales representative for access.
>
> When you reserve a regional external IPv6 address, a /96 range is
> assigned from the specified subnet.

```
gcloud alpha compute addresses create ADDRESS_NAME  \
        --region=REGION \
        --subnet=SUBNET \
        --ip-version=IPV6 \
        --endpoint-type=VM
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you make any estimated guess about the time this feature will go live (prod)?

Comment: No idea, I'm just a GCP user who also needs this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Reserve a static address page
Choose a name for the new address.

Specify whether it is an IPv4 or IPv6 address. Global IPv6 addresses can only be used with global load balancers.

Specify whether this IP address is regional or global. If you are reserving a static IP address for an instance or for a regional load balancer, choose Regional. If you are reserving a static IP address for a global load balancer, choose Global.

If this is a regional IP address, select the region to create the address in.

Optional: Select a resource to attach the IP.
Click Reserve to reserve the IP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the form at https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/addresses/add _does not allow_ me to select **IPv6** and **Regional**. (And I had already tried the **Global** type with no success.)

Comment: Use below gcloud command with verbosity this will reserve the external IPv6 :
 < gcloud compute addresses create <name_of_ipv6_address> --global --ip-version IPV6 --verbosity=debug >.

with this many of them got reserved their IP.

Comment: @FedKad : If the answer was useful, please mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for the community or upvote if the answer has some useful information.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I haven't be able to reserve any IPv6 address. If you [edit and extend your original answer] with more detailed (_and tested_) step by step actions, I can try it once more.

Comment: Try to Use the below gcloud command with verbosity this will reserve the external IPv6 : < gcloud compute addresses create <name_of_ipv6_address> --global --ip-version IPV6 --verbosity=debug > with this many of them reserved their IP.